# Problem to get cumulative function given a density function.

Tags: probability

In the picture the statement. How can $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=x^4$ if $y\geq x$ ? For me, if $y\geq x$, then $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$, and thus $$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_0^x\int_x^yf_{X,Y}(u,v)dudv=0$$
So how can (v) ask us to prove that $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=x^4$ if $y\geq x$ ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the density is $0$ for $y >x$ that does not imply that the distribution function is $0$ for $y >x$. For example, if $X$ has uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ then the distribution function is $1$ for $x >1$ even though the density is $0$ there. Hint for finding $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ when $y \geq x$: Calculate $P\{Y <X\}$ and use $P\{Y \geq X\} =1-P\{Y <X\}$.